# BeautifulSoup: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: beautifulsoup

I get an error when I run this function. I cannot figure out what I did wrong. I even tried removing ".text" and I still get the same error.

```
def get_detail_data(bs):
     title = bs.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text
     print(title)
```

Pycharm Error:

```
title = bs.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Entire code: https://pastebin.com/rsTmDgBD

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported selenium, but haven't used it. The `find_element_by_xpath` is not a BeautifulSoup method, but a selenium method. You probably have to start with something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="itemTitle"]').text 
print(title)
```